# Call blazor component on button click event

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Hi I have a child componenet positiongrid and I want to invoike this coponent on button click inside parent compoenet

Parent Compoenent Code below

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="DisplayPositionRefGrid">
          Create
        </button>
    </div>
</div>


   <div class="form-row" id="divPositionRefGrid" hidden="@HideGrid">
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
           <PositionRefGrid>

           </PositionRefGrid>

          
       </div>
   </div>
```

The issue is that the child component loading at the same time when the parent is loading but I want to load the child component on button click method 'DisplayPositionRefGrid'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Boolean variable to conditionally display the child component.

```cs
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="DisplayPositionRefGrid">
          Create
        </button>
    </div>


@if (ShowGrid )
{
   <div class="form-row" id="divPositionRefGrid" hidden="@HideGrid">
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
           <PositionRefGrid>

           </PositionRefGrid>

          
       </div>
   </div>
}

@code{

private bool ShowGrid {get;set;}

void DisplayPositionRefGrid()
{
  ShowGrid =true;

//other stuf
//...
}
}
```

[Try it online](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/czd25f3b)

Comment: I donot show /Hid ethe grid . I want to load the grid on button click as the grid will take some paramter from the parent compoennet and then when create button clicked the grid will dis[play

Comment: Pass the parameters of the grid from the parent  in the html code (if it have Parameter in the child component) e.g `<PositionRefGrid  data="employee" Display="wide">`

Comment: I want to restrict the gridview rows by slecting it from parent.That is hwy I want to create the grid on button click.Can you help me on this

Comment: What is the package components are you using for GridView?

Comment: Thanks a lot  M.Hassan .The solution you provided worked for me

Comment: Welcome, glad for your project is working.